# using primefaces tree to load database tables

Tags: jsf-2, treeview, primefaces

I have a database table with columns parentid, childid. I want to create a jsf tree view loading the table data using primefaces tree. the examples given are static data. Can someone help out please. I appreaciate. Thanks.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660458/how-to-create-a-dynamic-tree

Comment: That solution did not define nth node or steps.

Answer (score 3):

XHTML

```
<h:form id="form">  

    <p:tree value="#{dynamicTreeBean.root}" var="node" dynamic="true" cache="true" id="tree">  
            <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{dynamicTreeBean.onNodeExpand}" />  
        <p:treeNode>  
            <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>  
        </p:treeNode>  
    </p:tree>  

</h:form>
```

Java

```
import java.util.Random;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import org.primefaces.event.NodeExpandEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode;
import org.primefaces.model.TreeNode;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped

public class DynamicTreeBean {  

    private TreeNode root;  

    public DynamicTreeBean() {  
        root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
        TreeNode dynamicTreeNode = new DefaultTreeNode("First", root);
      //<Add dummy node: This is to have + sign in node to be able to expand it in GUI>
        TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("fake", dynamicTreeNode);
      //<Add dummy node>
    }  

    public TreeNode getRoot() {  
        return root;  
    }
    static Random random = new Random();
    public void onNodeExpand(NodeExpandEvent event) {  
        //<Remove dummy node>
        if(event.getTreeNode().getChildCount()==1){
            event.getTreeNode().getChildren().remove(0);
        }
        //</Remove dummy node>

        //<Generate some random children>
        int childrenCount = random.nextInt(9)+1;
        for(int i=0;i<childrenCount;i++){
            TreeNode tn = new DefaultTreeNode("-child-"+i, event.getTreeNode());

            //<Add dummy node>
            new DefaultTreeNode("fake", tn);
            //</Add dummy node>
        }
        //</Generate some random children>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your dynamic treenodes by creating a class that extends "**DefaultTreeNode**" and overwrite DefaultTreeNode methods to fit your needs and to use your proper data.

Then you create your own nodes by **instantiating** your new class.

You have just to provide the **root node** in your bean (with its get method).

Comment: can you please provide an example code? I'm having similar problem and cant get it right