# Primefaces tree from database

Tags: java, tree, primefaces

I have the following entity class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "THE_TREE", catalog = "", schema = "dbo")
public class TheTree implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "NODE_NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name = "LEVEL")
private int level;

@OneToMany    
@JoinColumn(name="PARENTID")    
public List<TheTree > children = new LinkedList<TheTree >();
```

I would like to represent this into primefaces tree, but I cant get it right. The example given in [primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/treeAjax.jsf) website has static nodes with predefined depth, where I need nodes with unknown depth and to be filled from database. I have seen various posts here but nothing is clear to me. In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660458/how-to-create-a-dynamic-tree) it seems the author has asked the same question but the answer is not relative to the question somehow. Any solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create a recursive function to make the tree. This is how I would do it:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TreeMBean {

    private TreeNode rootNode;

     @PostConstruct
     public void init() {
         TheTree root = new TheTree(); // instead get root object from database 
         rootNode = newNodeWithChildren(root, null);
     }

     /**
      *  recursive function that returns a new node with its children
     */
     public TreeNode newNodeWithChildren(TheTree ttParent, TreeNode parent){
          TreeNode newNode= new DefaultTreeNode(ttParent, parent);
          for (TheTree tt : ttParent.getChildren()){
               TreeNode newNode2= newNodeWithChildren(tt, newNode);
          }
          return newNode;
     }

     public TreeNode getRootNode() {
         return rootNode;
     }

     public void setRootNode(TreeNode node) {
         rootNode = node;
     }

 }
```

Comment: and also I'm sure you meant ttParent.getChildren() in the recursive method. please fix that :)

Comment: @fareed you are welcome, I edited the answer with the fix. regards

Comment: what is "TheTree" here. is it treeNode ?

Comment: @neni no, TheTree is an Entity in fareed's model.

Comment: how can you adapt this to utilize ajax?  Or specifically dynamic="true"

Comment: you can use it in the same way with dynamic="true". all nodes will be created at once in the server but only the expanded nodes are sent to the view. if you want to further optimize it, you could invoke newNodeWithChildren when a node is expanded instead of doing it recursively

Comment: @jeff see my comment above, I forgot to name you so that you get notified.

Comment: @Damian, Oh I didn't realize that is what dynamic did.  I though it lazily loaded from the database.  I have 16k entries so to recursively build the tree in one swoop from the db is not efficient.  I've been trying to use ajax onNodeExpand listeners.  I suppose I could use ApplicationScope and load the whole tree and use dynamic.

Comment: @jeff yes, if your tree is that big, I guess it's better to use onNodeExpand because doing it at once recursively will take time..