# Primefaces - Tree Component - Endless loop with repeated calls to recursive tree construction algorithm

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, treeview

I have searched the Internet and stackoverflow in particular and the only related thread I found with a similar case, was:

Primefaces tree from database ([Primefaces tree from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189697/primefaces-tree-from-database))[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189697/primefaces-tree-from-database).

I, my self can verify the validity of the proposed solution.

**However**, I face a *slightly* more *demanding* situation: The tree might *change depending on user input*: I have to find a way to **reconstruct** the tree upon user input. Therefore, I need to find a way to call the **recursive** method of tree construction (in the example it is: newNodeWithChildren) *outside* of the @PostConstruct method.

By doing so, I end up having the application server (Oracle WebLogic 12c in my case) entering an endless loop (live loop I would call it).

Any kind of assistance that might shed some light and lead me out of the current blind alley would be more than welcomed.

Should anyone have any further queries, please do not hesitate to contact me,

I would like to thank anyone in advance for his/her time, effort and concern,

Kind regards,

Nassos

P.S. Primefaces version: 4, JSF version: 2.*

Comment: Maybe you need to show some code. I took a look at that method and it's bound to end at some point. Are you sure that your implementation is actually in an infinite loop or is the request just timing out due to the size of the underlying table?

Comment: First of all I would like to thank you for your time, effort and concern. Since the problem I face is in a project at the office, I am afraid I shall better have to reconstruct it at home (instead of waiting for the weekend to end before I get my hands back on the respective original code snippet). Please, do bare with me as I proceed we the code reconstruction... Thanks again for your response

Comment: Mea culpa! I have traced the problem down to a live lock introduced due to inappropriate usage of a static variable. Primefaces and JSF are not to blame for incorrect behaviour! Sorry for any inconvenience caused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mea culpa! I have traced the problem down to a live lock introduced due to inappropriate usage of a static variable. Primefaces and JSF are not to blame for incorrect behaviour! Sorry for any inconvenience caused!