# Primefaces tree dynamically add siblings / children through commandButtons

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tree, treenode

I am trying to implement a dynamic tree structure in primefaces where the user starting from a `root node`, will be able to add `siblings` and `children` into each node through two `commandButtons`.

Example shown below:

**Root**

[image: Root]

**After add sibling pressed**

[image: ROOT sibling]

**After add child pressed (2 times)**

[image]

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660458/how-to-create-a-dynamic-tree/6660594), I have implemented the following structure:

**tree.xhtml**

```
<p:tree id="tree" value="#{treeController.root}" 
    var="node" dynamic="true" cache="false">
    <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{treeController.onNodeExpand}" />
    <p:treeNode>
       <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
       <p:commandButton style="width:50%; margin: 10px;" value="Add Sibling">
           <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{treeController.addSibling(node)}" update="@this"> 
           </p:ajax>
       </p:commandButton>
       <p:commandButton style="width:50%; margin: 10px;" value="Add Child">
           <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{treeController.addChild(node)}" update="@this"> 
           </p:ajax>
       </p:commandButton>
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

**TreeController**

```
     @ManagedBean(name = "treeController")
     @ViewScoped
     public class TreeController implements Serializable {

        private TreeNode root; //getters && setters ommitted

        @PostConstruct
        public void buildTree() {
            this.root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
            createNode("ROOT", this.root);
        }

        public void onNodeExpand(NodeExpandEvent event) {
            DefaultTreeNode parent = (DefaultTreeNode) event.getTreeNode();
            if (parent.getChildCount() == 1 && parent.getChildren().get(0).getData().toString().equals("ROOT")) {
                parent.getChildren().remove(0);
                createNode(parent.getData().toString()+ "'s Child " + (parent.getChildren().size() + 1), parent);
                createNode(parent.getData().toString()+ "'s Child " + (parent.getChildren().size() + 1), parent);
            }
        }

        public void addSibling(TreeNode node){
            // I need here the corresponding TreeNode element to add to it's parent a new TreeNode
        }

        public void addChild(TreeNode node){
            // I need here the corresponding TreeNode element to add into it a new child
        }

        private void createNode(String tag, TreeNode parent) {
            TreeNode node = new DefaultTreeNode(tag, parent);
            // Create Dummy node, just to make the parent node expandable
            new DefaultTreeNode("ROOT", node);
        }
}
```

However, onclick of the buttons I am getting `SEVERE [org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler] (default task-6) Method not found: TreeController.addSibling(java.lang.String)` which is caused due to the fact that the functions are expecting to receive a String parameter (node).

Is there any way to retrieve the TreeNode reference on the listeners of the buttons?

Maybe any NodeEvent like `NodeExpandEvent`?

**PS:** I am using `Primefaces 7.0` with `JSF 2.1`

Comment: Start by changing removing the explicit `p:ajax` tag from the `<p:commandButton ...>` and make it into `<p:commandButton style="width:50%; margin: 10px;" value="Add Child" actionListener="#{treeController.addChild(node)}" update="@this" />` Not sure it helps, but it is 'better'...

Comment: And please post your PrimeFaces version

Comment: I updated question and added it, I also changed the buttons as you suggested, nothing changed as expected :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation of p:tree](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/tree) `var` attribute:

> Name of the request-scoped variable that'll be used to refer each treenode **data**.

This is the first argument you pass to the node constructor:

```
org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode.DefaultTreeNode(Object data, TreeNode parent)
```

And as can be seen in your code and the exception it is of type `String`.

If you want to refer to the actual node, use the `nodeVar` attribute instead of / beside the `var` attribute:

> nodeVar: Name of the request-scoped variable that'll be used to refer current treenode using EL.

In your case you could modify the example like this:

```
<p:tree id="tree" value="#{treeController.root}" 
    var="node" nodeVar="theNode" dynamic="true" cache="false">
    <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{treeController.onNodeExpand}" />
    <p:treeNode>
       <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
       <p:commandButton style="width:50%; margin: 10px;" value="Add Sibling" 
        action="#{treeController.addSibling(theNode)}" update="@this" />
       <p:commandButton style="width:50%; margin: 10px;" value="Add Child"  
        action="#{treeController.addChild(theNode)}" update="@this" />
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

Comment: ahhh... you beat me ;-). Did not have a pc available earlier just a phone...

Comment: @kukeltje SO on Smartphone is no fun ... no IDE, hard to type special chars, bad typo correction sometimes even with wrong language setting :D. Are you still on holyday?

Comment: Keys is not the real problem with the https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard/ typo correction always switched off (see some of my posts ;-)) And no... sea, sand, sun (and cocktails and live music and golf) is over